# How do I update an entity?

Tags: entities

I have defined my own entity: 'game'; created some 'games' with `entity_create`; and loaded one of these 'games' into a form for editing. Now, I want to update the entity with my submit handler. Here is the relevant code inside the handler:

```
$game = entity_load_single('game', $form_state['values']['game_id']);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('game', $game);
$wrapper->some_property->set($form_state['values']['some_value']);
$wrapper->save();
```

This throws:

> **Error**
>
> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Entity property some_property doesn't
>   support writing. in EntityStructureWrapper->setProperty() (line 493 of
>   /.../sites/all/modules/contrib/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

I was looking for a function like `entity_update`, but it doesn't seem to exist. How can I update my 'game' entities? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`entity_save()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_save/7).

If you want to use a metadata wrapper for a custom entity properties you need to implement [`hook_entity_property_info()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info/7) to describe them to the entity module, especially `setter callbacks` which are used to set the value of the property.

Answer (score 0):

If you created your entity via `entity_create` (as you mentioned), you can set/override non-writable properties outside of the entity wrapper during the entity creation, e.g.

```
$entity = entity_create('games',
    array(                              
      'type' => 'game', 
      'changed' => REQUEST_TIME,     
      'some_property' => 'some value',        
    ));                                 
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('game', $entity);  
$wrapper->save();
```

Otherwise you'll need to write your own `setter callback` as already [suggested](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/130902/1908).

See also: [How to fix entity property X doesn't support writing, when setting content type field values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/69728/1908)