# After updating existing content How to get a token node:comment for actions?

Tags: rules, comments, updating

It was tried to change a term on a comment after updating existing content but there is no way to find the available token node:comment. Is there a possibility to have it?

Comment: content is node, so you want when you update a node something on the comments to change?

Comment: That's right. Is it possible?

Comment: I was able to get the comment tokens, but they are useless, nothing changes.

Comment: It's the same for me. I tried fetching comments from node, even for the rule After saving a new comment and I can't fetch all the comments. I think that if this action is done, it could be then accomplished for the first rule.

Comment: I got half way there.. On node update, I looped each comment to a rules component which checked for the term field and then set the term. But I ran into a "property doesn't support writing" issue with the field. That's for looping.. Is it just one or all comments you need to change?

Comment: There is an issue about support of property writing on DO - https://www.drupal.org/node/1080660. Haven't tried addressing it for comments, but the info maybe helpful.

Comment: more info in the answer here - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69728/how-to-change-content-type-field-values-with-the-entity-system-getting-a-doe?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Understood. Only one comment with a particular taxonomy term.

Comment: Nothing happens. It seems that Loop node:comments doesn't loop through comments ...

Comment: you need to loop through comment:node:comments