# After saving a new comment How to fetch all comments for a given node?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, rules, comments

Is it possible to fetch a list of comments for a given node by using the rule After saving a new comment? After this I would like to change a taxonomy term for a certain comment having a certain term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rule reacts on event `"After saving a new comment"`,
add a `Loop` in actions section and select `comment:node:comments` as a selector.

The loop will go through an array of comments from commented node. There you can specify additional actions/conditions that you wish to perform on each comment.

**PS:** You will run in the issue of not being able to modify comment fields via Rules

> "Unable to modify data "field-taxonomy-term": Entity property
>   comments doesn't support writing."

Here is more information about the issue:

- ["The selected data property doesn't support writing." when Action: Set a data value is applied to a taxonomy field:tid](https://www.drupal.org/node/1080660)
- [How to fix entity property X doesn't support writing, when setting content type field values?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69728/how-to-change-content-type-field-values-with-the-entity-system-getting-a-doe)

Comment: Is comment:node:comments an entity or anything else? Which data type must be used?

Comment: In this case - comment:node:comments is an array of all comment of the node that just received a new comment.